# Retrieving tweets from hashtag using curl

Tags: php, json, curl, twitter

I am trying to get the text and username for the most recent tweet using a certain hashtag (in this example, #stackoverflow) . The error returned is `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`. I assume this is because `$content` isn't actually an associative array.

```
function get_twitter($hashtag) {

    $json_url = "http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=%23" . $hashtag . "&rpp=1&result_type=recent";
    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 5;
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}

$returned_content = get_twitter('stackoverflow');
$content = json_decode($returned_content);
foreach ($content['results'] as $tweet) {
    echo $tweet['text'];
    echo $tweet['from_user'];
}
```

An example of the JSON that Twitter returns is as follows:

```
{
"completed_in":0.099,   
"max_id":210895419549548544, 
"max_id_str":"210895419549548544", 
"next_page":"?page=2&max_id=210895419549548544&q=%23stackoverflow&rpp=1&result_type=recent", 
"page":1, 
"query":"%23stackoverflow", 
"refresh_url":"?since_id=210895419549548544&q=%23stackoverflow&result_type=recent", 
"results":[ 
    { 
        "created_at":"Fri, 08 Jun 2012 00:46:00 +0000", 
        "from_user":"Beseeker", 
        "from_user_id":334048944, 
        "from_user_id_str":"334048944", 
        "from_user_name":"Italo Iv\u00e1n", 
        "geo":null, 
        "id":210895419549548544, 
        "id_str":"210895419549548544", 
        "iso_language_code":"es", 
        "metadata":{"result_type":"recent"}, 
        "profile_image_url":"http:\/\/a0.twimg.com\/profile_images\/1611497833\/imagen-perfil-fb_normal.jpg", 
        "profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/si0.twimg.com\/profile_images\/1611497833\/imagen-perfil-fb_normal.jpg", 
        "source":"&lt;a href=&quot;http:\/\/twitter.com\/&quot;&gt;web&lt;\/a&gt;", 
        "text":"podr\u00eda pasar horas y horas en #StackoverFlow", 
        "to_user":null, 
        "to_user_id":0, 
        "to_user_id_str":"0", 
        "to_user_name":null
    }
], 
    "results_per_page":1, 
    "since_id":0, 
    "since_id_str":"0"
}
```

Thanks in advance for any thoughts!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function getTweets($hash_tag) {

    $url = 'http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q='.urlencode($hash_tag) ;
    echo "<p>Connecting to <strong>$url</strong> ...</p>";
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    $xml = curl_exec ($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);

    //If you want to see the response from Twitter, uncomment this next part out:
    //echo "<p>Response:</p>";
    //echo "<pre>".htmlspecialchars($xml)."</pre>";

    $affected = 0;
    $twelement = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
    foreach ($twelement->entry as $entry) {
        $text = trim($entry->title);
        $author = trim($entry->author->name);
        $time = strtotime($entry->published);
        $id = $entry->id;
        echo "<p>Tweet from ".$author.": <strong>".$text."</strong>  <em>Posted ".date('n/j/y g:i a',$time)."</em></p>";
    }

    return true ;
}
```

Use like this:

```
getTweets('#yankees');
```

---

[Documentation](http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/search)

Comment: Wow. That's just ridiculously awesome. Thank you so much sir!

Answer (score 3):

This function doesnt' user oAuth and probably don't works anymore.

Answer (score 0):

The error is in your "foreach" loop. It should read:

```
foreach($status->results as $tweet) {
    echo $tweet->text;
    echo $tweet->from_user;
}
```